# MVC custom Delete function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have parse in ID and version to view in each table row. When i click delete i want parse id and version back to controller?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.version)
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item4)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "controller", new { id = item.ID, version = item.version })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

While my controller function is this

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, byte version)
    {
        webservice.Delete(out errorMsg,id,version);
        return Redirect("View");
    }
```

My model that i parse to view

```
public class Model
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }

        public byte version { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String item1 { get; set; }

        public string item2 { get; set; }

        public string item3 { get; set; }

        public bool item4 { get; set; }

    }
```

the way i parse them to view, everything can be display correctly except delete function

```
var gList= webservice.Get_list(DC, null, null, null, out retStatus, out errorMsg);

        var model = gList.Select(dc => new Model
        {
            ID = dc.ID,
            item1 = dc.item1,
            item2= dc.item2,
            item3= dc.item3,
            item4= dc.item4,
            version= dc.Version,
        })ToList();

        return PartialView(model);
```

Comment: So what problem are you having? Note you hidden input is not required. What is the html generated by `version = item.version`?

Comment: Code looks plausible. Please clarify what kind of problem you have with your code.

Comment: i get this error when i click delete.
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32, Byte)' in my controller. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters @StephenMuecke

Comment: Are you sure each item has an `id` value? (the error message suggest it does not). And I'm guessing version is actually a SQL TIMESTAMP field in which case you need other modifications. inspect the html and check what the `href` attribute is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes ID is Int32 value "-2147483648"

Comment: What is the `href` attribute your generating

Comment: <a href="/CAAOD/Delete?Length=5" id="-2147483648" version="0">Delete</a> @StephenMuecke i went to inspect code and this is what i find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `null` parameter for the `htmlAttributes` of the link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "controller", new { id = item.ID, version = item.version }, null)
```

Your `id` and `version` values are currently being added as html attributes, not route values.

Side note. You should not be generating a link for deleting items from your database. Its added to the browser history and a user can navigate to it. At best, it will be making an unnecessary call to delete something which no longer exists. and at worst it could throw and exception depending on your code. Instead, make the method `[HttpPost]` and use a form element with a submit button (the route values can be added in the `Html.BeginForm()` method

**Edit** (added code for using a form instead of a link)

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  ....
  <td>
    @using (Html.BegnForm("Delete", "yourControllerName", new { id = item.ID, version = item.version }))
    {
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> // style it to look like a link if that's what you want
    }
  </td>
  ....
}
```

Comment: i kinda of get what u mean but how do i change it to forms? current table is just to display out haha so u mean i have to put whole table in a form? @Stephen

Comment: No. A form in each iteration - I will update the answer in a moment with the code.